# How to read all message from Azure Service Bus topic using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I want to read all messages from azure service bus using python. Currently it fetch only one message.

```
from azure.servicebus.control_client import ServiceBusService, Message, Topic, Rule, DEFAULT_RULE_NAME

    bus_service = ServiceBusService(
        service_namespace='<NameSpace>',
        shared_access_key_name='<KeyName>',
        shared_access_key_value='<ConnectionString>')

msg = bus_service.receive_subscription_message('topic', 'msglist', peek_lock=True)
print(msg.body)
```

How can I get all the message in bulk from the topic with python 3

Comment: wanted to read all message in bulk

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by using a [`Receiver`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-servicebus/azure.servicebus.receive_handler.receiver?view=azure-python) object which supports batch operations. Refer [this sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus/samples/sync_samples/receive_subscription.py) which showcases how to get this object for a subscription.

To guarantee you get batches of messages, you have to set the [`prefetch` argument of `get_receiver()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-servicebus/azure.servicebus.servicebus_client.receiveclientmixin?view=azure-python#get-receiver-session-none--prefetch-0--mode--receivesettlemode-peeklock---receiversettlemode-peeklock--1----idle-timeout-0----kwargs-) to your batch size and consequently the [`max_batch_size` argument of `fetch_next()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-servicebus/azure.servicebus.receive_handler.receiver?view=azure-python#fetch-next-max-batch-size-none--timeout-none-) to the same.

Comment: the sample to showcase receiver object is not available

Comment: Thanks! Updated the link.

Comment: Thanks for updating the link :)