# Get message count from azure SubscriptionClient with python

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I am new to azure SubscriptionClient, I am trying to get the total message count from azure SubscriptionClient with python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try something like the following:

```
from azure.servicebus import SubscriptionClient

conn_str = "Endpoint=sb://<service-bus-namespace-name>.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=access-key="
topic_name = "test"
subscription_name = "test"
client = SubscriptionClient.from_connection_string(conn_str, subscription_name, topic_name)
props = client.get_properties()
message_count = props['message_count']
print message_count
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this help @gaurav Mantri.    It is working

Comment: Hi @gaurav Mantri, can you help with this question, --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60150669/how-to-read-all-message-from-azure-service-bus-topic-using-python

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
from azure.servicebus.aio import ServiceBusClient
from azure.servicebus.management import ServiceBusAdministrationClient

number_of_messages_in_subscription = 0
CONNECTION_STR = "<your_connection_string>"
with ServiceBusAdministrationClient.from_connection_string(CONNECTION_STR) as servicebus_mgmt_client:
 global number_of_messages_in_subscription
 TOPIC_NAME = "<your_topic_name>"
 SUBSCRIPTION_NAME = "<your_subscription_name>"
 get_subscription_runtime_properties = servicebus_mgmt_client.get_subscription_runtime_properties(TOPIC_NAME, SUBSCRIPTION_NAME)
 number_of_messages_in_subscription = get_subscription_runtime_properties.active_message_count
```

Source: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/1709ec7898c87e4369f5324302f274f254857dc3/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus/samples/async_samples/mgmt_subscription_async.py